# How to create a 64-bit build of an Opengl project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, 64-bit

I have a VS C++ 6 project that I need to create a 64 bit build for. The project uses opengl (which I have no experience of!) and requires the following libraries: glu32.lib, opengl32.lib and glaux.lib. Initially I'm upgrading it to VS2010 32 bit and then hopefully to 64. It's compiled ok apart from missing glaux stuff which I can't find anywhere on my Windows 7 system. I have the opengl SDK in the following folders: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A and C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A, and the 32 bit build is currently compiling ok against the v7.0A SDK (apart fronm glaux of course!). Also there is a glu32.dll and opengl32.dll in both C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64, so I'm assuming the libraries in v7.OA are compatible with the dlls?

I've had a look online for the relevant downloads but it appears to be a minefield! I'm hoping, therefore, that someone can tell me where I can get the necessary files to complete both my 32 bit and 64 bit builds.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything should be fine with regards to 64 bit. I would only dump the dependency on GLAux. What functionality from it are you using? You might find better alternatives.

Comment: Looks like it's just this: AUX_RGBImageRec *image = auxDIBImageLoad(fileName), any alternatives? Also, where do I get the 64-bit opengl dlls from? Cheers

Comment: @rob did you solve this error, if yes then will you please provide an answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

Counterintuitively the OpenGL libraries are called *opengl32.dll* and *opengl32.lib* on 64 bit Windows, too. Just link with them as usual and you should be fine.